# Saving a STAC - Error in the Item (float32)

Tags: geojson, netcdf, google-colab, stac

I keep getting this error no matter what I do or change when trying to save the catalog. To my knowledge, I don't have a random float somewhere in my code. I do not even know where to begin to debug this issue. I also got the same error when trying to run this line, but not for the catalog just the item. `print(json.dumps(item.to_dict(), indent=4))` Below is the code that got me here.

```
def dataset_to_geojson(dataset):
    # THE dataset is a NetCDF4
    # Assuming 'lat' and 'lon' are the variable names for latitude and longitude
    lat = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = dataset.variables['lon'][:]

    # Calculate the bounding box
    bbox = [min(lon), min(lat), max(lon), max(lat)]

    # Create the footprint polygon
    footprint = Polygon([
        [min(lon), min(lat)],
        [min(lon), max(lat)],
        [max(lon), max(lat)],
        [max(lon), min(lat)],
        [min(lon), min(lat)]  # Closing the polygon
    ])

    return bbox, mapping(footprint)

def toISO8601(stringDate):
    formattedDate = stringDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    return formattedDate
dataset = netCDF4.Dataset('https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/CoastWatch/VIIRS/npp-n20-s3a/chloci/DailyGlobalDINEOF/WW00/2022')
time = dataset.variables['time']
start_time = netCDF4.num2date(time[0], time.units, calendar=time.calendar)
end_time = netCDF4.num2date(time[-1], time.units, calendar=time.calendar)
bbox, geojson = dataset_to_geojson(dataset)
catalog = pystac.Catalog(id='NOAA MSL12 multi-sensor DINEOF global gap-filled products (aggregated)',
                         description='This my first attempt at a catalog.')
item = pystac.Item(id='2022 Agg Chla Global 9km Daily SQ DINEOF',
                 geometry=geojson,
                 bbox=bbox,
                 datetime=None,
                 properties={
                     'start_datetime': toISO8601(start_time),
                     'end_datetime': toISO8601(end_time)
                 })

item.add_asset(
    key='OpenDAP',
    asset=pystac.Asset(
        href='https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/CoastWatch/VIIRS/npp-n20-s3a/chloci/DailyGlobalDINEOF/WW00/2022',
        media_type=pystac.MediaType.HTML,
        title='OpenDAP Data Link'
    )
)
catalog.add_item(item)
catalog.normalize_hrefs(dir[0])
catalog.save(catalog_type=pystac.CatalogType.SELF_CONTAINED)
```

That last line is what raises the below error.
`TypeError: Object of type float32 is not JSON serializable`
I asked this on on the GitHub for STAC, but I came here to see if anyone here knows what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that the lat and lon values are stored as float32 in the netcdf file. So the numbers in your bounding box and geometry end up with `numpy.float32` as their type. You can check that by inspecting bbox:

```
>>> type(bbox[0])
numpy.float32
```

There are a couple ways to get around this. The most straightforward is to add `.item()` to convert from numpy type to python type:

```
from shapely import geometry
def dataset_to_geojson(dataset):
    # THE dataset is a NetCDF4
    # Assuming 'lat' and 'lon' are the variable names for latitude and longitude
    lat = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = dataset.variables['lon'][:]
    min_lon = min(lon).item()
    max_lon = max(lon).item()
    min_lat = min(lat).item()
    max_lat = max(lat).item()

    # Calculate the bounding box
    bbox = [min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat]

    # Create the footprint polygon
    footprint = Polygon([
        [min_lon, min_lat],
        [min_lon, max_lat],
        [max_lon, max_lat],
        [max_lon, min_lat],
        [min_lon, min_lat]  # Closing the polygon
    ])

    return bbox, geometry.mapping(footprint)
```

This solves the serialization error.